# Unable to scp files to Ubuntu 14 with Vagrant

Tags: 14.04, vagrant

I'm trying to scp files from my machines desktop into my vagrant box but I seem to keep running into this error.

```
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

I looked into my vagrant file and found this line:

```
 Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
# accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

I've tried running these commands and have gotten the following errors respectively:

```
scp -P 80 nginx.conf xxxxx@127.0.0.1:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
lost connection

scp -P 8080 nginx.conf xxxxx@127.0.0.1:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

I've tried running these commands but it still doesn't work either.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Vagrant docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/up.html), the correct way to SSH into a Vagrant box is:

```
vagrant ssh
```

Have a look at the configuration settings for [Vagrant SSH](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) to see how to manage SSH. Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704059/easiest-way-to-copy-a-single-file-from-host-to-vagrant-guest to see some ways of copying files to your Vagrant machine.

Comment: Thanks muru. Apparently, I found out that you can move a file on your host into your vagrant directory and it will be visible between your host and guest.

Comment: @DanRubio, yeah that's the second answer in the SO question I linked to. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

The lines you showed us are most likely for http access (with your web browser).

To find what port you have to use with ssh/scp follow the boot process after you typed `vagrant up`, you will find a line about forwarding a port 22->2200 (or similar).

Then you will have to specify "vagrant" as user to connect with the box. For plain ssh-access the standard `vagrant ssh` is easier.